# NRF24L01+PA+LNA communication problem

Tags: nrf24l01+, stm32

I'm trying to communicate between two NRF24L01+PA+LNA modules.

I know that NRF24L01+PA+LNA modules are consuming a lot of power and here is my 3.3V power circuit.

[image: LM317-based voltage regulator schematic]

The LM317 datasheet says it can output up to 1.5 Amp.
I'm not using Arduino, I'm using STM32F103 blue pill and I'm powering it from this single LM317 linear voltage regulator.

I'm using 1100 mAh, 8.4V LIPO battery, one for Transmitter module(NRF24L01+PA+LNA and STM32 Blue Pill) and second one for receiver module (also with NRF24L01+PA+LNA and STM32 Blue Pill).

**So my problem is that, when I'm TOUCHING the Transmitter's antenna somewhere in the middle with my FINGERS, then it transmits; If I'm not touching the antenna, it does not transmit.**

I also added additional 100uF polar capacitors between NRF24L01+PA+LNA's VCC and GND, but it does not help.

What else can I do?